Easy questions = More answers?
So I asked a day ago about how to monitor traffic and connections from and to my daemon and I got ZERO answers.
But I look at the main page and absolute beginner questions like: "What happens if I buy Bitcoins and the price goes down?" get 10 Answers, "GH/s is bigger than TH/s" gets an answer and stupid questions like "how to transfer to wallet" "or How to make totally secure Bitcoin transactions?".
This is depressing. Is there a lack of people who know this stuff? What's going on?

The "be nice" rule would seem to imply perhaps you should edit your title to remove the word "retarded".  Perhaps "simple" would be more concise and less rude.  And yes, I did notice your username.

Since it's obvious that beginner questions draw on a larger audience that can answer them, it's pretty obvious that they'll get an answer more easily.
So, what can we do to get interesting questions more visibility?
Please Vote early, vote often!.

Upvote interesting questions. 
Don't upvote boring, easy, or lazy content.
Close vote repetitive questions as duplicates.
Downvote bad content.


Some questions that are more technical require technically inclined people to answer them. Questions such as yours require people who actually know what they are doing, and there are far fewer of these people than just random people who can say something about the Bitcoin price or unit conversion. So yes, the simpler and more idiotic questions will get more answers as more people can answer them, and complicated technical questions will get less as fewer people can answer them.

Not to mention certain questions get on the HNQ ;-)

Unfortunately, I have the same problem. I asked a question about cryptography and got zero answers. 
I indeed think that easy questions generate more answers. 
